# How to create link for Mpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have one travel portal when user can book the tour . After the successful payment I am generating receipt in PDF form using MPDF.

After the successful payment users redirecting to my 'success.php' page where I am generating PDF. But the problem is whole success.php page is displaying as one PDF page . but I wanted to display the PDF as downloadable link.

my code is

```
       $template_data = str_replace('##WORDS##', $amonut_words, $template_data);

       ob_end_clean(); 

       include 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';

       $mpdf=error_reporting(E_STRICT);
       $mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);
       $mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
       $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($template_data);
       $mpdf->Output();

       exit();
```

Comment: Have you tried to leave the success page html and just embed the a link to this pdf php file?

Comment: Redirect them to success - then have a PDF download automatically at a different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to store your created pdf in folder using output();

ex;   `$mpdf->Output('pdf/filename.pdf');`

then you fetch the file and display .

```
echo "<a href='pdf/filename.pdf' >download </a>";
```

hope it helps you